# Importing a package with SMTP Connection Manager-SSIS 2017

Tags: sql-server, ssis, smtp, ssis-2017

I am trying to import a package to SSIS 2017 .I have  a SMTP connection manager in my package which is causing the issue while I import :

> OLE received a packet with an invalid extension. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010112) (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap)

I have tried removing the connection manager and did an import.It worked.

Can you please let me know if I am missing any assemblies?

Comment: try to create a new SMTP connection manager instead of using the old one after than you can compare the .dtsx xml file to see if there is any irrelevant property coming up in your old SSIS file.